# Declared empty initial state but getting "undefined during initialization error" in redux

Tags: redux

I'm getting **The slice reducer for key "Reducer" returned undefined during initialization** error.
I have initialized a empty state.

```
const initialState = {
    posts: []
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_POSTS':
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

```
Error: The slice reducer for key "Reducer" returned undefined during initialization. 
If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. 
The initial state may not be undefined. 
If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null instead of undefined.
▶ 3 stack frames were collapsed.
Module.<anonymous>
D:/Projects/Web/Ekart/client/src/Reducers/index.js:4
  1 | import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
  2 | import Reducer from './reducer';
  3 | 
> 4 | export default combineReducers({ Reducer });
  5 |
```

help please !!!

Comment: make sure you pass data through action. "return action.payload" may return undefined if payload is empty, so it can cause that error. You need to show your code more. How you pass the action.payload

Comment: Yes, I was sending empty payload. Fixed!. THANK YOU! for commenting.